# Can we merge this both tag [android-collapsingtoolbar] and [collapsingtoolbarlayout]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I noticed that [android-collapsingtoolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-collapsingtoolbar) and [collapsingtoolbarlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapsingtoolbarlayout)   both tags are  used for [**`CollapsingToolbarLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout)

- [android-collapsingtoolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-collapsingtoolbar)

  > CollapsingToolbarLayout is a wrapper for Toolbar that provides several visual effects that are bind to the content scroll events.
- [collapsingtoolbarlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapsingtoolbarlayout)

  > CollapsingToolbarLayout is a wrapper for Toolbar which implements a collapsing app bar. It is designed to be used as a direct child of a AppBarLayout.

I propose merging the tags [android-collapsingtoolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-collapsingtoolbar) and [collapsingtoolbarlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapsingtoolbarlayout), because Both the tags are used for question related to **`CollapsingToolbarLayout`**

Questions tagged [android-collapsingtoolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-collapsingtoolbar) :   297 questions
Questions tagged [collapsingtoolbarlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapsingtoolbarlayout)   :   813 questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[collapsingtoolbarlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapsingtoolbarlayout) and [android-collapsingtoolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-collapsingtoolbar) has been merged into [android-collapsingtoolbarlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout) to keep existing convention with `android-*layout` format.

Comment: Thanks  `android-collapsingtoolbarlayout` is better than both `collapsingtoolbarlayout` and `android-collapsingtoolbar` tags